# This operation is not supported within transactions

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two subforms in my microsoft access application that are very closely linked. These two forms are called Phases and Scenarios. Each form gets their records from the corresponding phases and scenarios tables. There are many scenarios for each phase in the database.

So on the form current event for the Phases form, I need to grab its unique PhaseID to filter the Scenarios Form. This all works well except when a Phase gets deleted. When a phase gets deleted, all associated scenarios get deleted as well. After the deletion, access will auto-select a new phase and when I try to apply the filter to the Scenarios form I get this error:

> Run-time error '2074':
>   This operation is not supported within transactions.

Here is my code:

Phase current event

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
   Dim filtStr As String
   Dim frm As Form
   Set frm = Forms!Main
   filtStr = "PhaseID=" & Me!PhaseID
   frm.Scenarios.Form.Filter = filtStr <--ERROR HERE
   frm.Scenarios.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Phase deletion event

```
Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
  Dim PhaseID As Long
  Dim Response As Long
  Dim style As Long
  PhaseID = Forms!Main!Phases!PhaseID

  style = vbYesNo + vbQuestion
  Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete this phase and all related scenarios and nodes?", style)
  If Response = vbYes Then
     deleteScenariosAndNodes PhaseID
     Forms!Main!Scenarios.Requery
  Else
     Cancel = True
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub deleteScenariosAndNodes(PhaseID As Long)
  Dim ESDHeadNodeID As Long
  Dim scenID As Long
  Dim rst_Del As Recordset
  Set rst_Del = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Scenarios WHERE PhaseID = " & PhaseID)
  While Not rst_Del.EOF
     scenID = rst_Del!ScenarioID
     ESDHeadNodeID = DLookup("ESDNodeID", "ESDNodes", "((ESDNodes.ESDNodeType)=1) AND ((ESDNodes.ScenarioID) = " & scenID & ")")
     DeleteESDChildren ESDHeadNodeID, False
     rst_Del.Delete
     rst_Del.MoveNext
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: What is code for DeleteESDChildren? Edit your question.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? add relationship to your tables and in MS-Access you can tick (Enforce referential integrity, cascade update, cascade delete). All you have to after that is to refresh!!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the OnCurrent code completely.

Then specify properties *MasterLinkFields* and *ChildLinkFields* of the subform control to: `[PhaseID]`

Also, if you applied *Referential Integrity* between the master table and the child table and set *Cascade Delete* to *On*, the remaining code could be reduced to:

```
Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)

  Dim Response As Long
  Dim style As Long

  style = vbYesNo + vbQuestion
  Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete this phase and all related scenarios and nodes?", style)
  If Response <> vbYes Then
     Cancel = True
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to be the right approach. I tried implementing this and I had a couple of issues. Firstly the Scenarios and Phases subforms are siblings and lie on the Main form which is unbounded. I know there is a workaround where I can give the main form a txt control that reads the PhaseID. I tried this workaround but it produces a noticeable lag and I could not get it to work properly. It would only show scenarios for one particular phase when it was selected and for all others, there were no records (even though I am certain there were).

Comment: Filtering will work but, I guess, you are filtering on a value not intended, or the values in the child tables vary from what you believe they are.

Comment: The phaseID of the auto-selected phase after deletion is sane and I even do a debug DCount and it shows the correct number of records it should be showing. The way [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223125(v=office.12).aspx) makes it sound like is that I can't filter a form when multiple records are deleted at once. Not sure why not...

Comment: Maybe if there is a way to detect if a transaction is open, I can skip the filtering code, and apply the filter to the scenarios form once the transaction is closed

Comment: Something else - outside what you describe here - must be going on, as you normally can delete and count of records in a (sub)form with zero issues.

Comment: Is there any way I could use the AfterDelConfirm Event to run the requery code? Because theoretically, the transaction should be complete at that point... only problem is, is that I do not know how to get it to trigger

Comment: That would be it. Or set a flag and run the code at the OnCurrent if the flag is raised.